# How can i add tooltip to action item in my index page of active admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tooltip, activeadmin

In my app's admin portal i added action item , on its click new resource opened. I want to add tooltip to it , to clarify where does this button take. How can i add tooltip in active admin.

Below is the code where i define an actionitem , i want to add tooltip here to give some information about this action item.

```
action_item  only: :index  do

  def permitted_params
     params.permit(:q => [:gender_eq , :date_of_birth_gteq , :date_of_birth_lteq , :relationship_status_id_eq,:occupation_id_eq, :qualification_id_eq ,:monthly_income_id_eq ,:common_interests_interest_id_eq , :location_id_eq, :number_of_people_at_home_eq ,:area_eq, :transport_id_eq , :like_count_in , :view_count_in , :view_greater_in   , :like_greater_in])
  end

  if !params[:q].nil?

     filter_user=User.search(params[:q])

     if filter_user.result.count > 0
        p=PsychographicsFilter.create(permitted_params["q"])
        session[:last_update]=p.id
        session[:associated_user_ids]=filter_user.result.map(&:id)
        link_to "Ask Question",  new_admin_psychographics_question_path(:post => { :filter_id => session[:last_update] , :users => session[:associated_user_ids]}) 

     end

  end
```

end

Comment: Add your view code and notify where you need tooltip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add tooltip on the action like normally we can add with link_to in rails

```
  action_item :my_new_action, only: :index do
    link_to 'Action Name', path_of_the_action, {title: "My Tooltip"}
  end
```

For your question just change this

```
link_to "Ask Question",  new_admin_psychographics_question_path(:post => { :filter_id => session[:last_update] , :users => session[:associated_user_ids]})
```

to

```
link_to "Ask Question",  new_admin_psychographics_question_path(:post => { :filter_id => session[:last_update] , :users => session[:associated_user_ids]}), {title: "My Tooltip"}
```

Comment: One more question do you know how to add progress bar in active admin

Comment: If it is working for you, you can mark as accepted, and ask new question for progress bar with details